# Does PHP execute files from an include in a file I compile with opcache.opcache_compile_file()?

Tags: php, opcache

The [PHP documentation for `opcache.opcache_compile_file` says:

> This function compiles a PHP script and adds it to the opcode cache
>   without executing it.

If I compile a file using `opcache_compile_file()`, and that file includes other files (via `include()`, `require()`, etc.), will the files that are included be executed? Or will the included files just be compiled and added to the opcache?

**EDIT**

From a point raised in a comment, are the included files also added to the cache? Or does `opcache_compile_file()` simply ignore includes (maybe the optimal behavior)?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to execute include files if you're not executing the file that includes them.

Comment: The real question should be whether the contents of the included files are included in the cache, or it has to execute those files when it later executes the cached file.

Comment: @Barmar I would agree, and that's what I'm hoping is the case. But it may not be fact. And your second comment is a really good question too - I'm added it to my top question.

Comment: Try it and see? Put `file_put_contents("/path/to/file.txt", "it ran it");` in an include file, then compile the file that includes it, and see if the file is written.

Comment: You can also use `opcache_is_script_cached()` to find out if the include file was compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having the same question ,i googleize and i got some results by turning on opcache in xampp with stackoverflow fellows

so i did my succefull stupid test ..

in php.ini i put these

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

and so in htdocs\stupidtest**index.php** i put this:

```
<?php
opcache_compile_file('test.php');
test();
```

in  **test.php** i put

```
<?php
function test(){
    echo 'yep';
}
```

and another file called **the_answer_i_need.php**

```
<?php
include('test.php');

print_r(opcache_is_script_cached('test.php'));  

test();
?>
```

Now let's play the game:
run first index.php
http://localhost/test/index.php in my case

then i run the_answer_i_need.php
http://localhost/test/the_answer_i_need.php  in my case

**the result i got is**
1yep

```
1 means boolean true
'yep' means the function called are included from cache cause the previous result was **true**

*job done,we're good*
```

i wrote the fastest php framework in the wold since 2002 and this trick will allow me to switch some parts of framework's core as 2nd pre procesor after the php and to gain around 40% more speed.